# Mathematical induction

Tags: inequality, induction, recurrence-relations

[image]

> The sequence of real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$ is such that $a_1=1$ and $$a_{n+1}=\left(a_n+\frac1{a_n}\right)^\lambda,$$
>   where $\lambda$ is a constant greater than $1$. Prove by mathematical induction that, for $n\ge2$,
>   $$a_n\ge2^{g(n)},$$
>   where $g(n)=\lambda^{n-1}\tag{6}.$
>
> Prove also that, for $n\ge 2$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>2^{(\lambda-1)g(n)}\tag{3}.$

I have trouble with the method of proving the inequality given. I have already proven that the base case where $n=2$ is true. But beyond that, I'm not sure how to go on.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_n \geq 2^{g(n)} \to a_n+\dfrac{1}{a_n} \geq a_n \geq 2^{g(n)}\to a_{n+1} = \left(a_n+\dfrac{1}{a_n}\right)^{\lambda} \geq 2^{g(n)\cdot \lambda} = 2^{\lambda\cdot \lambda^{n-1}} = 2^{\lambda^n} = 2^{g(n+1)}$.

Also, $a_n+\dfrac{1}{a_n} > a_n \Rightarrow a_{n+1} > a_n^{\lambda} \Rightarrow  \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > a_n^{\lambda-1} \geq (2^{g(n)})^{\lambda-1}=2^{(\lambda-1)\cdot g(n)}$

Comment: Do you mind explaining why $a_n+\dfrac{1}{a_n} \geq 2^{g(n)}$ ?

Comment: See my new edit...